# Encoding and updating bits with a checkbox - Succinctest method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

Is it possible to store a value (ie "1" or "0") in a `checkbox` `input` so that a secondary, `hidden` `input` isn't required to encode the *checked* status of it?

Currently I have a `form` with a `checkbox`:

```
<cfset is_cold = ""/>
<cfif IsCold EQ 1><cfset is_cold = "checked"/></cfif>

<form>
    <input name="chk_box" type="checkbox" #is_cold# />
    <input name="bit_val" type="hidden" value="#IsCold#"/>
</form>
```

The javascript that fires to map the `checkbox` state to a `bit` is:

```
$("input[name='chk_box']").click(function(){
    $("input[name='bit_val']").val($(this).is(":checked")?"1":"0");
});
```

I tried using the `value` *attribute* of `chk_box` to store the `bit` value, however it doesn't seem to work. Is there another *attribute* that could store the `bit` (allowing the elimination of the `hidden` `input`)?

Comment: radio inputs are set to thier value (if checked) or omitted (if unchecked). might need a 2nd hidden radio to make it "uncheckable", not sure if that's any cleaner than a hidden input...

Comment: Not certain interpret Question correctly ? If checked should return `true` or `1` , if not checked should return `0` or `false` . Where is `bit` stored ?

Comment: To clarify, you can always set/change the value of a checkbox on the clientside. However, [checkboxes are only submitted they are checked](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2).  On the server side either use `cfparam` to define a default so the form field always exists OR use structKeyExists as Alex described below.

Comment: The hidden field is simply not necessary.  Neither is any javascript.  Keep things simple and handle things on the server as described by Alex's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired behavior is implicitly provided by the checkbox input.

```
<!--- chk_box is only part of the GET payload, if checked on submit --->
<cfset bit_val = ( structKeyExists(URL, "chk_box") ? "1" : "0" )>

<!--- the [method] attribute of the <form> tag defaults to "GET" --->
<form>
    <input name="chk_box" type="checkbox" #( (bit_val eq "1") ? "checked" : "" )# />
</form>
```

In case of `<form method="post">`, replace `structKeyExists(URL, "chk_box")` with `structKeyExists(FORM, "chk_box")`.

Comment: `form` *method* is `post`, omitted. This works very well, thanks.